# Difference between 'next' and 'following'

Tags: word-choice, phrases

What different between this sentences? what is correct/incorrect?

Please check next items:

1) item 1

2) item 2

Please check the following items:

1) item 1

2) item 2

Thanks.

Comment: [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/next) says for *next*: "Immediately following, as in time, order, or sequence: next week; **the next item on the list**." And for [following](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/following) a. (prenominal) about to be mentioned, specified, etc: **the following items**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next comes immediately after; following may come anytime after.

In the example, only the *first* item in the list can be called "next,"  but all the other items in the list are "following."

Answer (score 0):

In a list such as this 'the following' is generally used.

Comment: I know :-),  but what different between 'next week' and 'the following items'?

Comment: 'Next' + time period means 'the time period after the current one. 'The next' = time period means the time period following a previously mentioned one. We do not use 'next' without the definite article before other nouns.  In the context of lists, we do not use 'the next', because it would suggest a previously mentioned list.

Comment: Aha! December 3rd you popped in. Which is reassuring, I thought something bad might have happened... I do hope that you change your mind and continue to contribute, I really appreciated your answers. (Did someone piss you off in EL&U? Or are you bored?)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Hi. I enjoyed the questions and answers, but decided I am too old to spend time deciding whether something should go as a comment or as an answer, and I am not into worrying about the finer points of whether a question is off-topic or not. So, I am spending my time in forums where I can concentrate on just helping people who have questions. EL&U is great for some people, but it's not for me. I shall miss some people, but I pop in occasionally to read what they have to say.

Comment: Oh, Mr Tunny I shall miss you. EL&U needs more users like you, who cares about whether something should be a comment or an answer as long as it helps the person who's asking! I shall miss your contributions, they were spot on and at times humorous. The "I have a bout of malaria"  will stay with me, as well as your explanation for try + to vs try + -ing.